# Proof of an application of the contraction mapping theorem to differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces

Please consider the theorem below together with the first part of its proof.

1) Why is M closed?

2) Why is M complete?

3) Why is the final integral a continuous function? (The curvy C denotes the space of continuous functions.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $M$ is closed since if $\phi_n\to \phi$ (under sup metric) and $\phi_n\in M$ then $\phi\in M$: Clearly $\phi$ is continuous as $\phi_n$ uniformly converge to $\phi$, $\phi(t_0)=x_0$ and $|\phi(t)-x_0|\le L\delta$ as $$|\phi(t)-x_0|\le|\phi(t)-\phi_n(t)|+|\phi_n(t)-x_0|$$
   and $|\phi(t)-\phi_n(t)|\to 0$, $|\phi_n(t)-x_0|\le L\delta$.
2. $M$ is a complete metric space since a closed subset of a complete metric space is a complete metric space.
3. (assume $u<v$) $$\left|\Phi(\phi)(v)-\Phi(\phi)(u)\right|=\left|\int_{u}^vf(s,\phi(s))ds\right|\le(v-u)L$$

Comment: Thanks, wonderful answer and great help!